# Iterating over a list / selecting data type for removal from source list with for loop

Tags: python

The code below seeks to append all ints from a (Python) list to  an empty list and then remove all ints from the source list leaving only strings:

The code is:

```
a = [101,'str1',3213, 'str845454654164',10183,25,14,33,8,"pfdr"]
b = []

for i in a:
    if isinstance(i, int):
        b.append(i)
for i in a:
    if isinstance(i,int):
        a.remove(i)
print("list a: ", a)
print("list b", b)
```

The output is however the following:

```
list a:  ['str1', 'str845454654164', 25, 33, 'pfdr']
list b [101, 3213, 10183, 25, 14, 33, 8]
```

All ints are successfully appended to list b but for some reason the numbers 25 and 33 are left behind in the source list a we wanted to clean up. Pasting the second for loop twice again under the first instance results in the desired outcome but isn't exactly good code.

Why doesn't this work as expected?

Comment: Don't change the length of the list while you're iterating over it...

Comment: Concurrent modification is definitely not the way to go. Try creating a temporary list or something similar.

Comment: Please make your question titles less vague

Comment: Got it: "Thou Shalt Not Modify A List During Iteration". Lesson learned. Thank you all!